# Icon images not appearing in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have created an ASP.NET MVC website and it is hosted off my existing site (www.joebooth-consulting.com/wibs). The mobile component relies on jQuery Mobile and uses the default MVC setup.   The CSS files are in the content folder and the images are in a folder called images within the content folder.   The icons-xx files are located there.

When I run the site in a simulator, the site looks and runs properly.   However, when I load the site on my iPhone, it works properly, but the jQuery Mobile icon images do not appear, I see blank circles.   I've copied the icons-xx files to different image folders, but cannot get the icons to show up.  I've look in the jQuery Mobile CSS files, and the reference is `URL(images\icons-18-images.jpg)`.

Anyone experience similar problems?

**NEW:**
I moved the .jpg files to scripts\images as suggested, but no luck.   Even stranger, I published the jQuery mobile version to the main site (rather than just the mobile) and I get the jQuery mobile menu and images when viewed in desktop Chrome or desktop Safari

**More Info...**
When I comment out my theme roller custom colors, the images come back...   More research ahead...

Comment: Have your tried using `<img src="" class="ui-icon">` instead?

Comment: Where would I use that?   These are not images I put in, but rather the default jQuery mobile icon images

Comment: Are you running this locally when in simulator? Or is the HTML online somewhere?

Comment: You need to define the position of the icon, for exampe, right arrow position is -108px; `.ui-icon-arrow-r { background-position: -108px 50%; }`

Comment: Sorry I keep commenting, but try putting the `/images/` folder under `/1.2.0/` = `1.2.0/images/icons-18-images.png` in case you're using CDN hosted JQM 1.2.0

Comment: The simulator works both locally and when I directly access the online site (www.joebooth-consulting.com/wibs).   iPhone runs site OK, just no icon images

Comment: `Scripts/images/icons-18-images.jpg` last trial. I checked the website on iPhone, the icons are not appearing and I checked the source of the page. If you locally host JQM JS and CSS without modifying CSS, then the images folder should go under `/Scripts/` where you have your JQM.

Comment: OK, thanks for the idea, I'll move them there tonight.     I suspected I have them in the wrong spot.   I'll let you know...

Comment: I copied the images to the scripts folder, but still no luck... Driving me crazier than I already am

Comment: Weird..JQM uses .png images I don't know whether .jpg files work the same way.

Comment: Meant PNG files, they are not JPG files, typo